# Understanding React refs - why is my reference null here?

Tags: reactjs, hammer.js

I have a use-case where a React ref makes sense.

I've tried a few different ways of implementing them, and in this case integrating them with hammerjs.

I'm mostly going off of this question:

[adding hammerjs to a react js component properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094487/adding-hammerjs-to-a-react-js-component-properly)

My return method in my render is as such:

```
  return (
    <div className={"App card-row card-color " + this.props.className} ref={
      (el) => this._slider = el
  }>
          {this.state.bubblemsg ? (
    <NotifBubble message={this.state.bubblemsg} merchant={this.props.merchant.merchant}/>
  ) : (
   null
  )}
      <ScrollMenu
        data={this.state.list}
        inertiaScrolling={true}
        transition={.1}
        inertiaScrollingSlowdown={.000001}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Which I would think would attach my div element as a reference.

In my componentDidMount() method, I am then attaching it to hammer:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.hammer = Hammer(this._slider)
  this.hammer.on('swipeleft', console.log("swipe left"));
  this.hammer.on('swiperight', console.log("swipe right"));
}
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

And this is directly related to Hammer, and thus the reference I assume.

So what am I doing wrong with my references? I don't totally understand how they're supposed to work and the React tutorial explanation wasn't super clear, so a thorough explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in the listening of the hammer you have to pass a function to be called, try inserting an arrow function to log

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.hammer = Hammer(this._slider)
  this.hammer.on('swipeleft', () => console.log("swipe left"));
  this.hammer.on('swiperight', () => console.log("swipe right"));
}
```

Comment: It appears that it's always null in componentDidMount(), and only not null in componentDidUpdate()

Comment: and did you see what is returning the Hammer constructor? Try to console log both this._slider and Hammer(this._slider) and see which is undefined

Comment: It appears I have to pass this._slider.current into hammer